# Passing parameter in select statement in postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am trying to pass parameter for below select statement in postgresql, but it is not returning any row,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", richTextBox_searchEmp.Text);                
string sql = "select * from tbl_emp_Info where LOWER(firstname) like LOWER('@name%');";
```

where- richTextBox_searchEmp.Text is “first”
have also tried -

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NpgsqlDbType.Char , searchEmp.Text);
```

while, parameter less query below always returning correct results.

```
 string sql = "select * from tbl_emp_Info where LOWER(firstname) like LOWER('first%');";
```

Please help!!!

Complete Code-

```
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NpgsqlDbType.Char , richTextBox_searchEmp.Text);

            string sql = "select * from tbl_emp_Info where LOWER(firstname) like LOWER('@name%');";

            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ds.Reset();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 7):

Pass your parameter with % like

Change you query  to

```
string sql = "select * from tbl_emp_Info where LOWER(firstname) like LOWER(@name);";
```

And Pass @name like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + searchEmp.Text + "%");
```

Comment: thanks Dnyanesh, tried this but not worked :(
I have implemented it in following way, but still searching for Parameterized way to do it.

              string sql = "select * from tbl_emp_Info where LOWER(firstname) like LOWER('" +  richTextBox_searchEmp.Text + "%');";

Comment: My bad remove single quote from sql string. so it will be @name and not '@name'. Now this should work. I have tested and it is working well. % before is optional if you want to search text anywhere in string.